# How to use commitHandler on dc.js?

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

I was looking into the dc-addons packages from Intellipharm. I am interested in the server chart, crossfilter server, and crossfilter server. Unfortunately, all of these functions are currently not working. Then from the blog I saw, There has been a fairly new addition to dc.js called commitHandler. This basically covers the functionality of crossfilter server. Wondering if someone could provide an example of how to use this api.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I apologize that this is not really an answer but just some pointers. There was too much for me to write in a comment!

The current progress on this is described toward the end of the long issue [dc.js#602](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/602), which links to [this example](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/webworker-example/web/examples/webworker.html).

We are not too far away, but the missing part is a server-side or webworker crossfilter component which defines [all of the filters that dc.js needs](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.filters.html).

If you're creating your own crossfilter-like server, such as many people have done using ElasticSearch and MongoDB, then hopefully this example will provide some clues.

**UPDATE 8-22-20:** There is also [xfilter](https://github.com/att/xfilter), which mocks enough of the crossfilter API to use an alternate backend. Its nanocube support is  out of date, but it provides some examples.

Please don't hesitate to ask if you have any questions. This might be a better discussion [for the user group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/dc-js-user-group) than SO. And if you'd consider publishing an example, I'm sure it would help a lot of people!